# Load IFRAME onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have IFRAMEs loading onClick.

The problem with the following script is that always loads the content of the first iframe, while I'm expecting to load JUST the right iframe when I click on the relative link.

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(){
var iframe = $("#myiFrame");
iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (1)
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe   
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (2)
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (3)
<iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe   
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (and so on...)
...
```

How to load just the iframe for the relative link?

Comment: An ID should be unique. You have three HTML elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the same ID. You can use a class:

```html
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (1)
<iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>  
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>// iframe (2)
<iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="my-url" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var iframe = $(this).next();
  iframe.attr("src", iframe.attr("data-src")); 
});
```

Comment: Thx. Your script doesn't work for me. I have just change 'id' with 'class' and now is ok.

Comment: Yes you need to replace id with class. That is what I meant