# How can I load iframe after function .overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two functions I want to happen, load iframe only after the clicking (not all iframes, just this one - per click) using the .overlay. There are multiple .overlays and iframes on the page.

I have checked out various sites and these work alone but I can not get both to work together.

overlay:

```
$(function() {
$("span[rel]").overlay();
});
```

iframe code option 1:

```
$(function() {
$('.overhover').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var iframe = $(this).next();
  iframe.attr("src", iframe.attr("data-src")); 
});
```

iframe code option 2:

```
$(function(){
    $(this).find("iframe").prop("src", function(){
        return $(this).data("src");
    });
});
```

My Code:

```
<a href="#" class="overhover">Test</a>
<iframe data-src="http://www.bing.com" src="about:blank">
</iframe>


<a href="#" class="overhover">test</a>
<iframe data-src="http://www.bing.com" src="about:blank">
</iframe>


<!-- Actual code -->
            <div class="res-item">
                <h4>Header</h4>
                <h2>
                    <!-- Overlay Link -->
                    <span class="overhover" rel="#tool3">Title
                    </span>
                </h2>
                <!-- Overlay Insert -->
                <div class="simple_overlay" id="tool3">
                    <iframe seamless="" data-src="http://www.bing.com" style="width:100%; height:75vh;" frameborder="0">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css not included here.
Thanks,

Load iframe:
[Load IFRAME onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080291/load-iframe-onclick)
and
[Is it possible to not load an iframe in a hidden div, until the div is displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437091/is-it-possible-to-not-load-an-iframe-in-a-hidden-div-until-the-div-is-displayed)

.overlay
http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/overlay/index.html

Comment: when you open the developer console on chrome or your browse what error does it print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your "Actual Code", this is what I would do:

### EDIT

I've modified the code so it actually does what you want. Also, modified your "original" code slightly for demonstration purposes.

```js
$(function() {
  var toolID;

  $("span[rel]").on('click', function() {
    //so we get the ID of the tool we'll be loading later
    toolID = $(this).attr('rel');
  }).overlay({
    onLoad: function() {

      var ifSrc = $(toolID + ' iframe').attr('data-src');

      $(toolID + ' iframe').attr('src', ifSrc);
      $(toolID + ' iframe').show();

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.simple_overlay iframe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tools/1.2.7/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<div class="res-item">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <h2>
    <!-- Overlay Link -->
    <ul>
      <li><span class="overhover" rel="#tool3">Bing</span></li>
      <li><span class="overhover" rel="#tool4">Duck Duck Go</span></li>
    </ul>
  </h2>
  <!-- Overlay Insert -->
  <div class="simple_overlay" id="tool3">
    <iframe data-src="https://bing.com" style="width:100%; height:75vh;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="simple_overlay" id="tool4">
    <iframe data-src="https://duckduckgo.com/" style="width:100%; height:75vh;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can take it from there, and modify it to suit your needs. Also, notice that bing's protocol is `https`, not `http`.  If you use the latter, nothing will load in the `iframe`.

Comment: Thanks for another option to load the iframe, but I need that to happen after the $("span[rel]").overlay(); happens.

Comment: Well, like I said, you can take it from there... By quickly reading their website, there's an onload event that you can define in the plugin options.  You can do something like this: onLoad: function() {  //code here  }.  If I can later on, I'll update my answer with a working example.

Comment: I edited my answer to a working solution that may help you get what you need.

Comment: Vash, Thank you very much for adjusting the code. I can use the script for the page.